# When using R to create custom hovertext with ggplot and plotly, I am getting an error. Can someone help me figure out where my error lies?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

```
cleanMarchdata = subset(marchData, Amount > 0, select = c(Transaction_Date, Amount, Merchant ))

marchgg  = ggplot(cleanMarchdata, aes(x= Transaction_Date, y = Amount, col = Amount, alpha = 1, text = c(Merchant,Amount)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')

ggplotly(marchgg,tooltip = 'text')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)

Comment: Could you share some data to copy and paste in our R, to make your code work? It's going to be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: column names are Transaction_Date , Clearing.Date, Description, Merchant, Category, Type, Amount                                                              A sample population of the set is 07/01/2020,
07/02/2020,
D J*WALL-ST-JOURNAL 84 2ND AVE 800-568-7625 01020 MA USA,
Wall Street Journal,
Other,
Purchase,
42.99

Comment: Could you provide `dput(head(cleanMarchdata))`?

Comment: structure(list(Transaction_Date = c("03/29/2020", "03/27/2020", 
"03/26/2020", "03/25/2020", "03/21/2020", "03/16/2020"), Amount = c(2.65, 
17.44, 10, 9.6, 37.31, 9.59), Merchant = c("7-Eleven", "Walmart", 
"Exxon", "chipotle online", "dick'ssportinggoods.co", "Amazon Marketplace"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like to see on your tooltip the concatenation of the variables `Merchant` and `Amount`. What about something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
marchgg  <- ggplot(cleanMarchdata, 
                   aes(x= Transaction_Date,
                       y = Amount,
                       # using fill = Amount, the bars are going to be coloured
                       col = Amount,
                       alpha = 1, 
                       # here you can use paste() to have two variables together 
                       # the sep is the separator, you can put whatever you want, like ": "
                       text = paste(Merchant,Amount, sep = " "))) +
           geom_bar(stat='identity')

plotly::ggplotly(marchgg, tooltip ='text')
```

[image]

If you use `c()` instead of `paste()` you'll stack the two vectors. To have a look, try  `paste(cleanMarchdata$Merchant,cleanMarchdata$Amount, sep = " ")` vs `c(cleanMarchdata$Merchant,cleanMarchdata$Amount)`.